# Using DataContract on Interface class?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a `classA` that is implements an `IClassA` interface.

Then WCF has a method that will be taking `IClassA` as paremeter, which we will actually be passing a `classA` object into the method.

```
public IClassA()
{

}

[DataContract]
public classA :IClassA()
{

}

//WCF:
public void MethodA(IClassA _objClassA)
{

}
```

For normal coding without WCF using `MethodA`, we can have no problem.

But when using WCF, the client side cannot find `ClassA` and `IClassA` interface in reference.

I wonder if that's is even possbile?

P.S. interface cannot use `DataContract` attribute.

Comment: My guess is that your client has no clue what `IClassA` or `ClassA` even is.  You need to share this knowledge by referencing the assembly containing those declarations or re-implementing them in the client (if that makes sense to do so)

Comment: @Marc Normally Client should knows IClassA when we are using it in the WCF method.  When client referece WCF, calling MethodA will shows I have to use 'IClassA' as input parameter.  But here is shows only 'Object' as parameter.  I wonder if is referencing the those assembly is a good way, doing that is means we have to give the assembly to every one who use it.  They cannot directly get the reference from WCF...

Comment: @Sheen and yes, I made typo lol Thanks Oded for edit btw

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Class Project within your solution, call it SharedInterfaces

Add the Interface class `IClassA` to that project. Then build the shared project and reference the dll in your WCF host and Client application. Then you wont have any issues.

Comment: I think you means the same as Marc? What if the Client application is not created by us?  Because the client application is going to created by 3rd party, so I will need to give them the dll file that defines the SharedInterfaces?

Comment: @King Chan, Yes this is basically what Marc suggested. Yes you will need send 3rd party these shared Assemblies. Q? Why would you want the the 3rd party to be able to extend this class?

Comment: we are developing a web service for the HQ development team actually (not really 3rd party), they will install our web service. So I am just thinking it maybe easier if all they need to do is just add the web service reference and able to have all the class definition. Rather than have them to need add another dll, then add web service reference etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an abstract class for IClassA, mark it as DataContract, use attribute KnownType[(typeof(ClassA))].

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ClassA))]
public abstract class ClassABase()
{

}

[DataContract]
public classA :ClassABase
{

}

//WCF:
public void MethodA(ClassABase a)
{

}
```